# Cluster Assignment in Bayesian perspective

Tags: bayesian, clustering, markov-chain-montecarlo

I am going to study clustering methods in the Bayesian perspective.
I understood how k-means works, and I found it pretty clear, due to the notion of distance and assignments to specific centers.

I am now turning the attention to the probabilistic approach and the use of mcmc methods.

I have read this question:

[Dirichlet Processes for clustering: how to deal with labels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135200/dirichlet-processes-for-clustering-how-to-deal-with-labels)

and a useful page:

https://snippyhollow.github.io/blog/2013/03/10/collapsed-gibbs-sampling-for-dirichlet-process-gaussian-mixture-models/

However, I do not understand how to assign points to clusters.
Which kind of posterior distribution should I compute?
What is the meaning of sampling from the posterior distribution in layman's terms?
Do I obtain a probability for each point to belong to any possible cluster?